# Iran relationship with Israel

Tags: international-relations, israel, iran

Have there been any friendly alliances, negotiations or agreements between Iran and Israel after the Iranian revolution, especially during the Iran-Iraq War? Or even some kind of help from any of the countries to the other?

Comment: @Noah, I just found this, there is allegation that Israel helped Iran during Iraq-Iran war, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%27s_role_in_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_war

Comment: @Noor Iran's public death to israel stance is well known policy, but for a specific example of it, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quds_Day#Quds_Day_events

Comment: The bombing of Osirak comes to mind: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera

Comment: I don't understand the reason of Putting the question on hold, the question is quite clear, is there any relationship between Iran & Israel, to contextualize, I stated the Iranian Revolution & Iran-Iraq, can I get some hints of how to narrow more the question ?

Comment: Iran's public "Death to Israel" stance is not a known policy and is the conflagration of lots of statements by individuals and also the misrepresenting of Farsi.  No official policy exists which cannot be explained through the prism of responding to Israeli actions.  The words of individuals do not represent the official policy of a theocratic Government.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The main Wikipedia article for this is the one on [Iran–Israel relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Israel_relations).

Among others it mentions [Israel's role in the Iran–Iraq war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%27s_role_in_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_war): Israel sold weapons to Iran.

Israel's relationship to Iran seems to have been a pragmatic one: The enemy of my enemy (Iraq) is my friend. That changed in the 1990s after the defeat of Hussein's Iraq and the rising fear of an Iranian nuclear program.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Give more detail. Anyone can post articles. Give a summary of the links you posted. (I didn't down vote btw)

Comment: @Noah: I don't want to repeat Wikipedia.

Comment: In addition to your answer which should be marked as answered, since it is correct - the OP would do well to see the following links http://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2015/02/iran-hassan-rouhani-iranian-jews.html which indicates a gorwing tolerance of the Jewish faith in Iran which several Jewish film makers have testified to.